# Is there a way to tell gradle always to use a custom binary of aapt2?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build an Android project on an arm64/aarch64 Debian server.
Unfortunately the Android SDK only comes with a AMD64 compatible version of aapt2, which wont work to build the android project on arm.
I found a aarch64/arm64 built binary of aapt2 on github here and it works:

https://github.com/JonForShort/android-tools/tree/master/build/android-9.0.0_r33/aapt2/arm64-v8a/bin
https://github.com/JonForShort/android-tools/tree/master/build/android-11.0.0_r33/aapt2/arm64-v8a/bin

My question is if there is a way I can tell build.gradle to only use my binary of aapt2 instead of downloading it to somewhere in ~/.gradle/caches?
So far I found a fix, but it only works with

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
```

The fix is outlined here in this blogpost:

https://linuxtut.com/en/ec63aa8bff5103982156/

The TLDR of that blogpost is you can take the jar containing aapt2 in ~/.gradle/caches/.... and unzip it and replace the aapt2 binary with the amd64 compatible version of aapt2 and then rename it back to .jar . Then when you run a build again then it will use that jar containing the arm compatible aapt2 version.

The problem is if I change

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

in gradle.build then it just downloads a binary of aapt2 (not inside a jar ) to:

```
$HOME/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d26ef9244e179eadf69140d97f4d45bf/aapt2-4.2.0-7147631-linux/aapt2
```

even if I replace aapt2 in that location and rerun the build, then gradle will redownload the amd64 compatible version of aapt2 to that location.

That is why I would like to know how to use my arm64 compatible version of aapt2 on all my builds.

I've even tried copying it to /usr/bin/aapt2 and adding it to my path, but that also didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am in the same boat now trying to build on Graviton (arm64) as well. What solution did you end up taking?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this line in your gradle.properties

"android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=path to custom aapt2 binary"

In my case, the path is /usr/bin/aapt2

Note that gradle has deprecated that option for a while and it might have been completed removed in the gradle version you are using to build your project.